# How to deal with error related to photon package in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have been trying to install `photon` package from Git hub repository [`ColumbusCollaboratory/photon`](https://github.com/COVAIL/photon/tree/master)

After installation and loading the package. When I try to invocate **miniUI**, error displays:

```
photon:::photon_rstudioaddin()
Error in if (getAttribs(panels[[i]])$value %in% open) { : 
the condition has length > 1
```

Full Code:

```
remotes::install_github("ColumbusCollaboratory/photon")
library(photon)


photon:::photon_rstudioaddin()
```

Comment: It looks like there hasn't been any changes to the code in at least 3 years. Newer versions of R have more strict checking of conditions passed to `if` statements. It seems the code in this package does not comply. You might want to install a 3 year old version of R if you really need to use this package.

Comment: The package appears to be defunct - your issue has already been reported to the maintainers by [several users](https://github.com/COVAIL/photon/issues/40) without response.

Comment: The bug is at being triggered upstream in `shinyBS`, namely in [`bsCollapse()`](https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/blob/shinyBS3/R/bsCollapse.R#L30). From the look of [shinyBS#50](https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/issues/50), it looks as if this bug was reported 8 years ago with no attention paid.

Comment: Since there is https://github.com/COVAIL/photon/pull/43, you might be able to get yours to work if you install the PR itself (since `devtools::install_github` supports installing from pull requests.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice. I'm just trying to convert a Shiny App into  a .exe file.